# JOOQ vertx AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor transaction management

Tags: transactions, vert.x, jooq

I am going through JOOQ with vertx and trying to use AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor for query execution. It looks like

```
AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor queryExecutor = new AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor(client);
Future<Integer> updatedCustom = queryExecutor.execute(DSL.using(configuration)
            .update(Tables.SOMETHING)
            .set(Tables.SOMETHING.SOMEREGULARNUMBER,456)
            .where(Tables.SOMETHING.SOMEID.eq(something.getSomeid())));
```

link : https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-classic-async

If you see implementation of execute method in class AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor it creates database connection inside it.

```
public Future<Integer> execute(Function<DSLContext, ? extends Query> queryFunction) {
        return getConnection().compose(safeExecute(sqlConnection -> {
                Query query = createQuery(queryFunction);
                log(query);
                Future<Integer> future = Future.future();
                sqlConnection.updateWithParams(
                        query.getSQL(),
                        getBindValues(query),
                        this.<UpdateResult,Integer>executeAndClose(UpdateResult::getUpdated,
                                sqlConnection,
                                future)
                );
                return future;
        }));
    }
```

link : https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-classic-async/src/main/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/classic/async/AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor.java

I was looking for transaction management here. Does AsyncClassicGenericQueryExecutor provides any transaction management? or we have to write custom code for it? Also if database connection is created inside execute method (which is jooq implementation), how can we write some custom transaction code above that as transaction has to happen on single connection. Can anyone please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but there is a suggestion of how to add Vertx Transactions in Kotlin:
https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/issues/66

Comment: yes I went through that link. But I dont see any assured response from jooq community